What was the first video game to allow players to use custom photos for character faces?
I recall that NBA Live 2000 (1999) on PC had an interesting "Face in the Game" feature where players could import photos to create custom basketball players with their own faces. While the feature was somewhat wonky, it was still a novel attempt at personalizing character appearances through real photos.

Face in the Game was a feature of Create a Player in the PC versions of NBA Live 2000 and NBA Live 2001 which allowed users to create their own cyberface from a suitable photo for use with a custom player. On-screen instructions prompted players to position markers around facial features so that the game could properly capture them when creating the custom face.



Face in the Game in the PC version of NBA Live 2000

- NLSC Wiki, "Face in the Game"
I'm curious to know which game was the first to implement this kind of feature—allowing players to import their own image files to be used as character faces in the game.

No clue if it's the oldest example but apparently Leisure Suit Larry 7 from 1996 allowed inserting one's face according to the manual at page 13.

@Pilzkopf good find - but not sure if that's used for "character customization", at least the manual doesn't really say, other than it puts your face in the game somehow.... would need to see gameplay of it I guess?
